# Similar function as "Create TABLE as" but to add further information

Tags: mysql

I have used the following to create a table from a select query

```
CREATE TABLE Dailystatsheet AS (select query)
```

I would like to run this select query dialy and add the results to Dailystatsheet. Is there a similar way as the CREATE TABLE method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first day you can use

```
  CREATE TABLE Dailystatsheet AS (select query)
```

but for adding the result the next days you could use an Insert/select query

```
insert into Dailystatsheet
select query
```